# SUMIFS with nutritional data

Tags: excel, sumifs

I am trying to create an Excel file that will keep track of some nutritional information.  I have three sheets as follow:

Sheet1: food, amount eaten
Sheet2: food, foodgroup
Sheet3: how much of each foodgroup eaten

I want to update Sheet1 with what I've eaten (say 50g avocado), then Sheet2 will have a row (AVOCADO, FRUIT), and Sheet3 will tally up how much FRUIT I have eaten (50g).  I have been trying to use a SUMIFS function in Sheet3 that looks like:

```
=SUMIFS('Sheet1'!B:B, 'Sheet1'!A:A, "="&'Sheet2'!A:A, 'Sheet2'!B:B, "=Fruit")
```

I thought this would take each food in Sheet1, search for it in Sheet2, see whether it was a fruit, and then add the amount eaten from Sheet1.  I was wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest in two steps, assuming data is top left of each sheet and labelled:

In Sheet2!C2:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!A:A,A2)
```

in Sheet3!B2

```
=SUMIF(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet3!A2,Sheet2!C:C)
```

adjust references if necessary and copy both formulae down as required.

The problem with your version is that you are feeding a criteria set where a single criterion is expected. ie Excel does not like `"="&'Sheet2'!A:A`.